# I have a CSV file which is connected as database and I want to update column values not all column using query from automation anywhere

Tags: database, csv, automationanywhere

I have connected CSV file as database in automation anywhere tool and i want to update certain column values using update query.

```
Update [$vOutputFileName$] 
Set [column 7] = 88 
Where [column1] = "5744543"
```

When I use this query, I get an error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ' instead of "

This is from MS Reference.

```
 Other incorrect formatting like extra spaces in the SQL statement can also cause this error.
```